# How to execute Stored Procedure from Laravel - SQL Server

Tags: laravel

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spx_kasir_verifikator_GetData_web]
@id_verifikator int
as
begin
    SELECT * FROM tb_kasir_set_verifikator 
    WHERE tb_kasir_set_verifikator.id_verifikator = id_verifikator;
end
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id_verifikator)
{
    $setverifikator = DB::select("exec spx_kasir_verifikator_GetData_web ?",[$id_verifikator]);
    dd($setverifikator);
}
```

And I'm trying to call this procedure in Laravel 8, I need to display just one id or by id_verifikator but it's always showed all data. How I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning everything as you are using `select *` which tells the database that you want the entire row. If you wish to only get a specific column then you need to change that to `select id_verifikator`.

A bit off-topic but I would suggest that you just run this query in Laravel instead of having a procedure, especially as this is such a basic query. The below links can help you get started.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: I tried to change select * with select id_verifikator and I got just one column which is id_verifikator and it still showed all the rows at coloumn id_verifikator. Then I used @ at = @id_verifikator; then it works.

Thank you for your kind heart to answer this question. It means a lot. Thank you